# How can I validate data against injection attack when tables are varchar()

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sql-injection

A lot of the tables at my company don't type input when they should.  For example, many tables are keyed with `varchar(##)` when the only valid values are `int`.  Due to a list of now cemented in dependencies, I simply cannot just go flipping all the data types.

So, in the short term I want to provide some manner of validating data to prevent Bobby Drop Tables from stopping by for a visit.

In this particular case I should be running read queries.  I need to validate the `Order` property:

```
public class Model
{
    public string Order { get; set; } // In DB this is a varchar(20)

    public aType Read()
    {
          var result = from a in table
          where a.Column == Order;
          select new { ... };
    }
}
```

How can I validate user input against my Model?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. I mean, you can simply check the data type within your programming language and fail if it doesn't match what you expect. Did you need something more?

Comment: @tom h. - mvc has some attributes one can add to methods for some level of data validation, but I dont remember their names or if the solve injection issues.  Knowing LINQ paramiterizes makes the attributes seem irrelevant...in this case, thats why i marked the question mvc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both Linq2Sql and Linq2Entities uses sql-parameters behind the scenes to pass any variables in the queries. You won't get any SQL injection attacks, but someone might be able to insert a string that is not just numerical characters.

One way to make sure you can only insert "numerical" strings is to create a constraint in the database. That will make sure all applications that uses the database behaves correctly, but does not force them to change datatypes.

**Edit**
If you use Linq2Sql and you want to have a check within your application you can implement the partial method `OnValidate` on the specific type in your Linq-context.

Comment: +1 - @Albin Sunnanbo Haha, I've been looking for a selling point for LINQ and this is it!  Thanks.

Comment: LINQ is fantastic.  I'm not sure of any metrics on performance, but its awesome.  I haven't written a SQL query or sproc in over a year.  Granted, if you want to change your linq logic, you have to rebuild the app and not just update a sproc.

Comment: The selling point of Linq2Sql is not that it prevents SQL injection. You get that with plain [`SqlCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx)s if you use parameters, the selling point is that it gives you type checking at compile time and that it simplifies writing joins.

Answer (score 2):

Using LINQ, the way you're using it, prevents SQL injection.

As long as you're using parametrized queries, you're in the clear.